# Why Google Slides not Autofit text in placeholders?

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

I have a simple slide where the placeholders are all set in: Shrink text on overflow.

Despite this, the text is not reduced and through the Api I discover that the Autofit is not set.
In setting it, however, I get the following error: `Autofit types other than NONE are not supported`

Code of requests:

```
requests = [
            {
        "updateShapeProperties": {
            "objectId": 'gda51db96da_1_5',
            "shapeProperties": {
                "autofit": {
                 "autofitType": 'TEXT_AUTOFIT'
                }
             },
        "fields": "autofit.autofitType"
        }

            }
        ]
```

Comment: also happened to me, copy of presentation lost autofit setting for slide's title box

Comment: I get "batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid requests[4].updateShapeProperties: Autofit types other than NONE are not supported. "  'autofit': {
          'autofitType':'TEXT_AUTOFIT'
         ,'fontScale': 0.90
        }                                      issuetracker.google.com/issues/189153562

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue, and needs a fix from Google's end.

Ref: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191389037